# SQL server DWU usage metric

Tags: azure-synapse

do we have a API interface to gather data that is populating following graph?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is how i was able to get same result via API

```
https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{sub-id}/resourcegroups/{rg-name}/providers/microsoft.sql/servers/{server-name}/databases/{db-name}/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2018-01-01&metricnames=dwu_used&aggregation=average&interval=P1D&timespan=2022-08-15T00:00:00.000Z/2022-08-19T23:59:59.000Z
```